# Many-to-many relationship creating duplicates

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm creating a many-to-many relationship which involves three tables, one table for the Game object and one table for the Player object.

Every time I create a new game, which should reference existing players (unless new players are involved), new duplicate players of existing players are created... I created a function to try and solve this issue... it looks like this. I think I'm close to solving the problem, but I have no idea what to put into the else code block to get the game to map to the existing players.

```
private void SaveNewPlayers(Common.Game newGame, Data.Game dataGame)
{
    foreach (var player in newGame.Players)
    {
        var isNewPlayer = player.PlayerId < 1;  //The reason I do this is because on the front-end, 
//when a new player is written in rather than selected they receive a negative ID so they can be distinguished
        var playerData = MapToData(player); //This just converts the front end Common.Player 
//to a replica Data.Player object so it's database ready

        if (isNewPlayer)
        {
            Context.Players.Add(playerData);
            dataGame.Players.Add(playerData);
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {


            //Context.Players.Add(playerData);
            //Context.SaveChanges(); //Doing this adds clone Players to the database but not the relational database

            // dataGame.Players.Add(playerData); //Doing this adds clone Players and relationship to the database
            //Context.SaveChanges();


        }
    }

}
```

I feel like a simple function I'm not aware of should address this, but I'm having a hard time finding what I need.  Apologies if this has been asked, I looked, but couldn't find something as specific as this.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the players you add already existing in given context, or you get them from some other context? Or maybe you create a new ones?

Comment: Let me explain the front-end... it's a data entry program for a hockey team.  The user goes to a page to create a game to add to the database.  On that page a bunch of game data can be added and when players are added to the game I have a typeahead box.  

When they type in a new player then that player is added to the database, when they type in an existing player, it's selected from the database.

Once Create Game is clicked all that data is then sent to the logic which is where the above code is handled

Comment: where is `isNewPlayer` defined? are you sure that code block is hit?

Comment: That was a typo when bringing the code over that I corrected with an edit just now.  isNewPlayer is a boolean.  I actually just solved this myself and will post an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You may be forgetting to add the attached entity to `dataGame`:

```
var pData = Context.Players.Add(playerData);
dataGame.Players.Add(pData);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

The entity has to come from the db not some newed up instance.

Comment: That was essentially it, I went about it slightly differently, but solved the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me:

```
private void SaveNewPlayers(Common.Game newGame, Data.Game dataGame)
{
    foreach (var player in newGame.Players)
    {
        var isNewPlayer = player.PlayerId < 1; 
        var playerData = MapToData(player);
        if (isNewPlayer)
        {
            Context.Players.Add(playerData);
            dataGame.Players.Add(playerData);
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            EditPlayer(player, dataGame);
        }
    }

}
```

and then created this function

```
    public void EditPlayer(Common.Player alteredPlayer, Data.Game thisGame)
    {
        var playerData = Context.Players.Where(p => p.PlayerId == alteredPlayer.PlayerId).First();

        playerData.PlayerId = alteredPlayer.PlayerId;
        playerData.Goals = alteredPlayer.Goals
        /*etc... etc...*/
        playerData.Games = playerData.Games;
        playerData.Games.Add(thisGame);

        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```